# How to implement A'B + AB'D with 3 nand gates?

Tags: boolean-logic

I have simplified the function F = (A+B)(A'+ D')(A' + B') with a k-map and narrowed it down to A'B + AB'D . However, I can't find out how to simplify it down to (at most) 3 nand gates.

Comment: Your simplification is wrong. `A'B + AB'D` is true when `A=T,B=F,D=T` but `(A+B)(A'+ D')(A' + B')` is false; the middle term `(A' + D')` is to blame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplified expression is:

```
F = A' B  + A B' D'
```

Karnaugh map:

[image]

Transformed into NAND gates:

```
F = NAND2(NAND2(A', B), NAND3(A, B', D'))
```

If desired, the inverted inputs can be created via `NAND` gates, due to

```
X' = NAND2(X, X)
```